# (C/C++) libjpeg, missing "Release.obj" file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, libjpeg

I downloaded jpeglib-9a. In Visual studio (2012) command prompt I typed this:

```
nmake /f makefile.vc setup-v10
```

It created several files and one of them was named "jpeg.sln" which I opened in visual studio (updated to 2012 version) and built. After that, I made new project, included this folder "D:\Data\jpeg-9a" and added this folder "D:\Data\jpeg-9a\Release" to linker.

And when I tried to compile my project, this error appeared:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'D:\Data\jpeg-9a\Release.obj'
```

I was looking for that file but couldn't find it anywhere. I also tried compile that library again but "Release.obj" is still missing.

This is the tutorial which I was following 
http://www.dahlsys.com/misc/compiling_ijg_libjpeg/index.html

So is there any way how to create that file ?

Thank you.

(if you need additional information, ask me)

---

SOLVED: ... I cant read properly ...

Thank you bogdan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create that file.

The linker is interpreting the `D:\Data\jpeg-9a\Release` directory name as an input `.obj` file name. Most likely, this is happening because you added the directory name in the wrong place in the linker configuration property pages. My guess is that you added it under `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`; that's not the right place for a directory - that property is supposed to contain a list of `.obj` and `.lib` files to be given as input to the linker.

You need to add the directory under `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories`.